# How to use single docker compose to build containers in different directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to spin up two containers when I do docker-compose up

I have two folders API and front. Each has a Dockerfile and docker-compose file. currently, I have to do docker-compose up for each app.
like below

```
- api
 - docker-compose.yml
 - Dockerfile
- front
 - docker-compose.yml
 - Dockerfile
```

I want to have one docker-compose.yml to manage two containers like below.

```
- docker-compose.yml
- api
 - Dockerfile
- front
 - Dockerfile
```

api docker-compose
version: '3'

```
services: 
    api:
        build: .
        command: pipenv run start
        image : data-tracker-backend
        volumes: 
            - .:/api/
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
```

front docker-compose
    version: '3'

```
services: 
    web:
        build: .
        command: npm start
        image : data-tracker-front
        volumes: 
            - .:/front/
        ports: 
            - "5000:5000"
```

I want to have something like

```
version: '3'
    services: 
        api:
            build: .
            command: pipenv run start
            image : data-tracker-backend
            volumes: 
                - .:/api/
            ports: 
                - "8000:8000" 
        front:
            build: .
            command: npm start
            image : data-tracker-front
            volumes: 
                - .:/front/
            ports: 
                - "5000:5000"
```

help to access the command from the different working directories.

Comment: The `build:` directories, and the first half of the `volumes:`, are relative to the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml`.  (But I'd suggest deleting the `volumes:` and `command:` in favor of what's built into the Docker image.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the build directory and the volumes one.

```
version: '3'
  services:
    api:
      build: ./api
      volumes:
        - ./api:/api
      # the rest of your commands...

    front:
      build: ./front
      volumes:
        - ./front:/front
      # the rest of your commands...
```

My suggestion though is to read the guidelines. It's plenty of [information](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) and [tutorials](https://docs.docker.com/samples/#tutorial-labs) there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use build `context` and `dockerfile` as shown below

```
- docker-compose.yml
- api
 - Dockerfile
- front
 - Dockerfile
```

```
version: '3'
  services:
    api:
      build:
        context: api
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      command: pipenv run start
      image : data-tracker-backend
      volumes:
        - .:/api/
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    front:
      build:
        context: front
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      command: npm start
      image : data-tracker-front
      volumes:
        - .:/front/
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
```